# Javascript: How to undo the removal of options using remove() within a dropdownlist?

Tags: javascript, html

I got two DropDownList: `Min_Price` & `Max_Price` and javascript that remove the option from both DropDownList if matched the condition. E.g: if `$ 30,000` from DropDownList `Min_Price` has been selected, options with DropDownList `Max_Price` will be removed but without removing the default value `Max. Price` option. Is there a way to undo the permanent removal of options? Is there any logical error I had made? Thank you.

```js
var minPrice = document.querySelector('[name="Min_Price"]');
var maxPriceOptions = document.querySelectorAll('[name="Max_Price"] option');
var maxPrice = document.querySelector('[name="Max_Price"]');
var minPriceOptions = document.querySelectorAll('[name="Min_Price"] option');
var reg = /[\$\,]/g;

// Remove the lower value options from Max_Price DropDownList when a selected value in Min_Price DropdownList is greater than the Max_Price
minPrice.addEventListener("change", function(e){
    var v = +e.target.value.replace(reg, "");
    Array.from(maxPriceOptions).forEach(el=>el.value!==" " &&+el.value.replace(reg, "")<=v && el.remove())
});

// Remove the greater value options from Min_Price DropDownList when a selected value in Max_Price DropdownList is lower than the Max_Price
maxPrice.addEventListener("change", function(elems){
    var vr = +elems.target.value.replace(reg, "");
    Array.from(minPriceOptions).forEach(ele=>ele.value!==" " && +ele.value.replace(reg, "")>=vr && ele.remove())
});
```

```html
<select name="Min_Price">
    <option value=" ">Min. Price</option>
    <option value="0">$ 0</option>
    <option value="10000">$ 10,000</option>
    <option value="20000">$ 20,000</option>
    <option value="30000">$ 30,000</option>
    <option value="40000">$ 40,000</option>
    <option value="50000">$ 50,000</option>
</select>

<select name="Max_Price">
    <option value=" ">Max. Price</option>
    <option value="10000">$ 10,000</option>
    <option value="20000">$ 20,000</option>
    <option value="30000">$ 30,000</option>
    <option value="40000">$ 40,000</option>
    <option value="50000">$ 50,000</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `hidden` property for the option element instead of removing!

```js
var minPrice = document.querySelector('[name="Min_Price"]');
var maxPriceOptions = document.querySelectorAll('[name="Max_Price"] option');
var maxPrice = document.querySelector('[name="Max_Price"]');
var minPriceOptions = document.querySelectorAll('[name="Min_Price"] option');
var reg = /[\$\,]/g;

// Remove the lower value options from Max_Price DropDownList when a selected value in Min_Price DropdownList is greater than the Max_Price
minPrice.addEventListener("change", function(e){
    var v = +e.target.value.replace(reg, "");
    Array.from(maxPriceOptions).forEach(el=> { el.value!==" " && el.value.replace(reg, "")<=v ? el.hidden = true : el.hidden = false;} )
});

// Remove the greater value options from Min_Price DropDownList when a selected value in Max_Price DropdownList is lower than the Max_Price
maxPrice.addEventListener("change", function(elems){
    var v = +elems.target.value.replace(reg, "");
    Array.from(minPriceOptions).forEach(el=> { el.value!==" " && el.value.replace(reg, "")>=v ? el.hidden = true : el.hidden = false;} )
});
```

```html
<select name="Min_Price">
    <option value=" ">Min. Price</option>
    <option value="0">$ 0</option>
    <option value="10000">$ 10,000</option>
    <option value="20000">$ 20,000</option>
    <option value="30000">$ 30,000</option>
    <option value="40000">$ 40,000</option>
    <option value="50000">$ 50,000</option>
</select>

<select name="Max_Price">
    <option value=" ">Max. Price</option>
    <option value="10000">$ 10,000</option>
    <option value="20000">$ 20,000</option>
    <option value="30000">$ 30,000</option>
    <option value="40000">$ 40,000</option>
    <option value="50000">$ 50,000</option>
</select>
```